# In-App Purchase - Restore only one product

Tags: ios

I am currently implementing the restore functionality for my app. I have several In-App Purchase products (non-consumable) and I want to allow the user to restore only one or two, so that I don't download more content than needed. In the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9) its stated that I can do that like this:

```
NSMutableArray *productIDsToRestore = <# From the user #>;
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = <# Current transaction #>;

if ([productIDsToRestore containsObject:transaction.transactionIdentifier]) {
    // Re-download the Apple-hosted content, then finish the transaction
    // and remove the product identifier from the array of product IDs.
} else {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

However, in my experience, the product ID doesn't match the transaction identifier. By product ID I understand the string used to retrieve the products from the App Store (something like "com.mydomain.myproduct"). The transaction identifier seems to be a long number, even if it's received as a string.

What am I missing and how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this - (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue{
   
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        if ([productID isEqualToString:@"YourProductID"]) {
            // Show confirm messagebox
           
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}

Comment: please mark answer as accepted if you can